# No property, bindable property, or event found for 'Tapped'

Tags: xaml, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms, prism

I am getting compile error with `Image`'s `Tapped` `Binding` using Prism MVVM.

> No property, bindable property, or event found for 'Tapped', or
>   mismatching type between value and property.

This is my code

```
<Image Source="bell.png"  HeightRequest="25" WidthRequest="25" x:Name="yellowBoxView"
     RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
     Type=RelativeToParent,
     Property=Height,
     Factor=0.018,Constant=10}"
     RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
     Type=RelativeToParent,
     Property=Width,
     Factor=0.85,Constant=15}">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="{Binding GetStaffAnnCommand}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Delete bin/obj folders and rebuild if you haven't done this already

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try and bind to the `Command` property instead:

```
<Image.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding GetStaffAnnCommand}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
</Image.GestureRecognizers>
```

Hope it helps & happy coding!